# Collection List with reverse order

Tags: android, collections

how to reverse the allReminder List having object of class type
example:

```
  List<Reminder_Model> allReminder
```

Comment: This is not the purpose of Stack Overflow. You should try a solution, share it with us and then we can look to help you. Don't just ask a solution here.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use collection

```
Collections.reverse(List<?> allReminder);
```

Comment: this is working ..thank you {Collections.reverse(List<?> allReminder)}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Reminder_Model> reversedList = new List<>();

        for(int i = allReminder.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
        Reminder_Model  reminder_Model = allReminder.get(i);
        reversedList.add(reminder_Model);

        }
```